# Unanswered Questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the “Unanswered Questions” tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-show-questions-that-have-answers)

What's the deal with the functionality of "unanswered questions"? It's showing questions with answers.

Comment: It's because nobody has 'accepted' an answer.

Comment: It shows questions with no upvoted answers

Answer (score 5):

This is how questions are shown under unanswered -

- All questions which have 0 answers
- All questions which have more than 0 answers but 0 answers with upvotes