# Suggestion: Solving unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Would it be possible to have a “community accepted” feature?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3669/would-it-be-possible-to-have-a-community-accepted-feature)

I think user with high rep should be able to select an answer of unresolved questions older than a week or so, this way many open questions would be answered and closed. Thanks.

Comment: I answered this one instead of VTC as a dupe because it seems to be specifically about cleaning up unanswered questions (and likely a misunderstanding of exactly what that term means).  The question proposed as a duplicate is proposing a similar thing but for an entirely different reason.

Comment: @aarobot Normally I'd sink my teeth deep into a question like this, but I've got work to do, lol.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-show-questions-that-have-answers (almost any user can help "solve" the problem of unanswered questions by simply up-voting the good answers)

Answer (score 2):

Answers don't need to be accepted to get the questions off the "Unanswered" page.  The question only needs to have a net answer upvote score of 1 ("net" meaning the sum of all upvotes and downvotes for all answers).

At least I think that's how it works.  It's either that, or it only needs a single upvoted answer.

Either way, the solution is the same: If you want it off the unanswered page, just upvote the good answers as you should be doing anyway.  We don't need to force an acceptance and the functionality doesn't need to be limited to high-rep users.

Acceptance does not signify a "correct" answer, it signifies the answer that worked *for the person who asked the question.*  If that person has not accepted an answer, it makes no sense for anybody else to make that claim.

Comment: Pretty sure it's the net score of *any* answer - a massively-down-voted answer won't keep a good one from making the question answered.