# Why are there some questions with answers in the "Unanswered" list?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the “Unanswered Questions” tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-show-questions-that-have-answers)

I found some questions which have answers, but are still categorized as "Unanswered." Here is one [example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?page=203&tab=votes).

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, a question is "unanswered" if:

1. The OP has not accepted an answer.
2. There are no answers with upvotes. (or no answers with a positive vote count, not sure which)

Comment: Argh, I have a pet hatred for people listing multiple conditions for something without making clear whether there should be an 'and' or an 'or' between each of them. (Legal documents do it all the time; usually techies are better about it.) After a second's thought, I assume there must be an implicit 'and' here, but I'd rather not have spent that second.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I definitely meant an "and".