# Answered Questions appear in the "Unanswered Questions" List

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, information-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the “Unanswered Questions” tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-show-questions-that-have-answers)

When viewing unanswered questions, many of them show several answers, even in the icon in the list of questions, but still appear in the list. Is this a bug? Why does this happen?

Comment: It took me 5 minutes of looking for what was happening before running into the answer obliquely, in a discssion about the ethics of downvoting answers to re-mark a question as unanswered.

Comment: There's a blog post describing the rationale for this as well: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/

Answer (score 1):

When a question has no answers with more than 0 reputation, it is considered unanswered.

Once any of the answers have been upvoted above 0, they will no longer be considered unanswered, and will no longer appear on this list.