# Android app : longer titles are clipped

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

I'm using the official app, 1.0.43 on Android 4.1.2, Samsung S3-mini.

The title of a question is sometimes clipped. Sometimes I only see part of the last line, sometimes I don't see the last line at all.

[image: screenshot]

One example is this question itself - the second line ('clipped') is partly visible. Another one is [Why is the last unanswered page in the unanswered tab of Stack Overflow containing the answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153442/206420) - the third line is partly visible, the 4th is completely hidden.

I just  noticed: when I switch to landscape the 2nd line is completely hidden.

As far as I can see the display of every question does not change, when I open it repeatedly.

Comment: Can you link to a question where this happens for you? Does it happen all the time on the same question?

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi thx for looking into this. I hopefully answered your questions.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi according to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237681/long-titles-spanning-3-rows-or-more-sometimes-obscured-by-tags-on-the-android-ap) it happens for all questions where the title spans more than one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fixed as of version 1.0.44 coming out in the next 24-48 hours, thanks!

Comment: 1.047 is now available on Google Play, issue is fixed. Thank you!