# A question [solved] but unanswererd due to lack of information

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Almost a year ago I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27965175/reading-a-file-returns-invalid-token-errors) on SO which got some comments and two answers. After a short while I solved it with the help from the comments (and not from the answers), much like in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171245/solved-yet-unanswered-questions) (I did not put "Solved" in the title however).

The only difference, and point which made me ask this question, is however that the way to solve it is explicitely not an answer to the question, and is not an answer someone can come up with based on how I asked the question (I might be wrong here, please say so if), and neither would I be now as I forgot most of the details.

So what to do then?

- Answer it based on the comments, which with the limited supplied information would be otherwise impossible and probably will confuse people who look at it (just like it now confuses me).
- Delete it, which would make up for the seeming uselessness of the question but probably is not in line with the general spirit of passing as much knowledge as possible to other people (bad questions don't exist, right?).

<sub>Another possible option would be to improve the question, but I cannot at this point as I don't have access to the original code anymore and have no clear memories of it as well.</sub>

Comment: Also, why is it impossible to edit the question just because you can't paste in the old code? You can certainly remove distracting things, and add a line like "I was also verbing the noun using the AmazeLib library, but I can't show that code because I am no longer on the project" if such an addition helps make your question more useful.

Comment: Since I have abandoned the project, I also forgot most details surrounding it, specifically for that question as well. Because of that, I am actually looking at the question now as someone who only has the information in the question and the comments. I will clarify that in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You answer it. You can mention the commenters if you want to, but if you have put together things from parts of the comments and parts of the answers and some other stuff you went off and tried that nobody here mentioned, then writing all of that up into an answer is useful.

You can even accept the answer to send a strong signal to other people "this is what helped me most."

Now on the matter of "how you asked the question" if you asked "When I A and B, it doesn't C, and I don't know why" and it turns out A is irrelevant, then you can just edit the question to "when I B, it doesn't C" so as not to distract people. But if your question is actually a common misconception, like getting delete/erase/remove confused when they do wildly different things in your language, framework, or platform, then leave the question how it was and include a nice sensible explanation in your answer. That way whether someone searching knows the right words (and will find them in your answer) or has the same misconception (and will find it in your question) they will still end up where they need to be: enlightened.

Answer (score 4):

There are several cases:

1. The question was just missing some information.  That information didn't fundamentally change what the question is asking, it's just some data that was missing.

   In this case you should edit the missing information into the question, so that it becomes answerable.  Then you can post your answer.
2. You've realized, based on the comments (or other outside information) that the question  you asked isn't actually an accurate description of your problem, what your *real* problem is is actually a radically different question.

   Here, comment on the question explaining the situation, and then just do nothing more with this question.  If someone else can answer the question (even if it doesn't relate to your situation) then great.  If not, that's fine too.

   If you want, you could, at this point, ask a new question that *does* accurately represent your situation, and post it with your answer, so that others can benefit from that information (if this is a problem that would actually be applicable to others).

Comment: Point 1 is impossible, as explained in this question. Point two is indeed a nice solution, and I already did at that point put a comment down, but that comment is not visible as it is the seventh comment and not up-voted. How would that work out?

Comment: @SimonKlaver There isn't really anything else to do.  The comment isn't even necessary.  The fact that the question isn't relevant to you, while good to mention, as a courtesy, isn't really relevant, strictly speaking.