# Feed lists answered questions as "unanswered"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app, ios-app

I do not know whether it's a bug or a feature.  In the feed under `unanswered` header there are questions with answers. I can even see how many answers each question got.

[image]

I've checked again and the very first question listed under `unanswered` tag has an **upvoted** and **accepted** answer.  So by [SO standard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-show-questions-that-have-answers) this question is clearly **answered**. App itself shows **green** bubble for this question, so apparently it can detect that this question has been answered.

Comment: I can reproduce this from questions from about a week ago. But if I recall, the devs said the feed was a snapshot in time and was cached. Not a live view on each refresh. I'm not succeeding at finding that post though...

Comment: The description that's in line with the intent here is probably closer to "Needs Answers," but while it's more technically accurate, it doesn't work because its less descriptive - someone new has no way to guess whether that means roughly zero (the reality) or "fewer than 10", or "none with at least 5 upvotes", etc.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange has its own definition of "answered." A question is "answered" only after it has at least one *upvoted or accepted* answer.

Comment: What you are saying seems to be inconsistent with the behavior of `unanswered` tab on the web-site.  There I see only questions with no posted question.

Comment: @PM77-1 Looking at the [last page on the unanswered tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=30545&sort=unanswered), I see questions with many answers, but none of them are upvoted.

Comment: This is true. The first question that was shown under this header has upvoted accepted answer. It's marked with green, so app is aware that it has been answered.

Comment: @PM77-1 Oh...crap. I didn't notice that you had tagged this `android-app`. My answer might be totally invalid.

Comment: Why? I believe the definition of "answered" should stay the same across all platforms.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, but it still might be displayed incorrectly on the Android app. I don't have it, so I can't verify anything.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: The [Android app still shows this in err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou6Ow.png), even though [the question has answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/58594/10308).

Answer (score 3):

This, as strange as it is, is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). The questions *were* unanswered when they got added to your feed, they are not anymore.

Each time you pull to refresh on the feed it looks for more things to add into yours and does so. However, it's possible for one of the questions we considered as "unanswered and this user might be interested in" to come back and get an answer later on in the day (or even sooner), making it so that "unanswered" label no longer applies. It still displays however, since it *was* unanswered when they label was made.

I don't really have a big problem with how this works right now, what I do have an issue with is the fact that the label doesn't change. This becomes a little bit more complicated when you have a series of unanswered questions returned, let's say 3, and the first one in the list gets an answer. Now the label applies to items 2 and 3, but not to item 1. I'll gladly take any suggestions for how we can change this on the presentation side.

Comment: I'm not a fan of a Feed view in the first place. (The same way I view the list of "hot questions" as an unnecessary distraction.)  But if you have to have a Feed view, then do not allow it to become stale. It's not just a presentation problem - it's a data synchronization problem.