# Feed shows unanswered questions - which are answered

Tags: bug, ios-app

The ios-app (v. 0.1.54) showed on top of my feed a section called "2 unanswered".
But the second question is already answered (with an accepted answer which has 3 upvotes as of this writing).

See here:
[image]

Comment: Related, since both the Android and iOS apps use the SE API: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217143

Comment: I've gone ahead and answered this on the related question, and made that for both the ios and android apps since it's the exact same issue.