# Answered Question Unanswered

Tags: bug, ios-app, feed

On Feed, sometimes it shows questions that already have an answer (even accepted answers). The questions seem to be random. Questions from all sites can be affected.

#### Example 1

> [image]

#### Example 2

> [image]

Related: [Feed lists answered questions as "unanswered"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217143/feed-lists-answered-questions-as-unanswered) (please note this has an answer that does not apply to this situation -- the answers have upvotes and are marked as answered, but the corresponding questions are still marked as "unanswered".)

- App Version: 1.6.3.6
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)

Comment: I see this regularly on Chrome (Desktop and Mobile)

Comment: So this is not iOS-exclusive?

Comment: No.  I have just seen it's a fairly frequent meta question.