# Filter questions by 'Unanswered' and select 'newest' not working

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, sorting

I was looking for newest unanswered questions, so I clicked the 'Unanswered' button and then, the 'newest' tag just below.

Why did I get answered questions in the displayed list ? Isn't it supposed to filter the questions by unanswered and sort the list from newest to oldest unanswered questions ?

EDIT : I don't want it filtered by a specific tag like C++ for example nor sort by upvotes like the 'no answer' tag. Just unanswered and sort by newest.

[image: Filter by Unanswered AND newest]

Comment: @psubsee2003: Oops, that's right, I kneejerked a little there.

Comment: Thanks @psubsee2003 ! Referring to the answer, why is there also accepted answers included in the list too ? Is that a bug or something in that way ?

Comment: @GabrielL. probably caching.  many of those lists are cached on the server side to speed things up, so if the answer was accepted after the cached page was generated, you would see it in the list.  That's by design and if you refreshed the page, it would go away pretty quickly.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I just saw that this is true. You should post it as an answer because the link and the answer helped me to understand. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have 2 issues going on here.

First, you are misunderstanding the definition of "unanswered".  In Stack Overflow-ese, an unanswered question is any question with no answers, no accepted answers, or no upvoted answers.  This definition is explained in the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) entry [Why does the "Unanswered Questions" tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-show-questions-that-have-answers).

However, your screenshot does show a question with an accepted answer, which is contrary to the definition I just gave you.  Despite the fact that it looks like a bug, it isn't.  Many of the pages on Stack Overflow and the other Stack Exchange sites are heavily cached, for performance.

That answered question you are seeing was likely accepted after the cached page was generated.  A refresh would clear that up pretty quickly when you would get a newer version of the cached page.

Comment: Is that accepted answer question not included due to the fact none of the answers have upvotes - rather than a caching issue? I agree it 'shouldn't' be however.

Comment: Effectively, I was misunderstanding the definition of "unanswered". [+1] for the great explanations. Thanks.

Comment: @GabrielL. if it wasn't for the oddball caching issue throwing off the defintion, I probably wouldn't have answered.  The duplicate covers this perfectly so in reality it wasn't needed.

Comment: @Chris No, it is caching.  Once the question has an accepted answer, it is considered "answered".

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). The 'Unanswered' section shows all questions where answers have no upvotes, with the logic that these answers haven't been 'validated' in any way I assume.

You'll see next to the 'newest' tab, there's also a 'no answers' tab, which is what you want, I think.

I would say that accepted answers probably shouldn't be included there though...that's surely some form of validation!

As from the side of that page:

[image]