# Unanswered question does not show up in Unanswered Questions list

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18871/202205):

> The Unanswered Questions tab shows questions that have no answers with a positive score nor an accepted answer.

So then why does [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22476/would-humans-starve-if-spiders-disappeared), which only has one answer with a negative score, not show up in the Skeptics [Unanswered Questions](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes) list?

Comment: Related: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1456/why-is-this-question-not-in-the-list-of-unanswered-questions

Comment: Possibly the same as [Question with no upvoted or accepted answers missing from unanswered question list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247285/question-with-no-upvoted-or-accepted-answers-missing-from-unanswered-question-li)

Comment: @ff524 That issue appears to be resolved now, but this issue is still unresolved.