# Searching for unanswered questions with two or more tags returns answered questions

Tags: bug, tags

I want to search for unanswered questions having two or more tags.

When searched with `/unanswered/tagged/java+and+json`, I get list of questions that already have answers.

[image]

Comment: edited the question

Comment: What are those answers scored? It seems like this question may now be a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18870/323179).

Comment: yes, I guess it is.. the answer to that question resolves my curiosity. thanks!