# Stack Overflow tag 'info' column has wrong styling of the "unanswered" tag

Tags: bug, tags, design, unanswered-questions

Recently I've noticed a small design oversight while visiting the PHP tag's `info` page. When on this page the `unanswered` button shows as a tab, while on all other pages this shows as a button.

[image: Tag in info]
[image: Tag in newest]

Pages used here:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=frequent&pageSize=15

Comment: Clicking the two "unanswered" links also takes you to [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=unanswered) [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/php), which show a different set of questions. (The second page [doesn't count unaccepted zero-score answers.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-show-questions-that-have-answers))

Comment: So even more confusion, UX really has to take a look at it then 