# "Unanswered" section displays mostly answered questions...?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why does the “Unanswered Questions” tab show questions that have answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18870/why-does-the-unanswered-questions-tab-show-questions-that-have-answers)
>   [Unexpected Results From Clicking The Unanswered Button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4146/unexpected-results-from-clicking-the-unanswered-button)

When I go to the "Unanswered" section of Stackoverflow most of the listed questions are answered.  Is this right?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11568/why-does-unanswered-show-answered-questions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11773/why-inside-unanswered-tag-there-are-questions-that-have-already-been-answered http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18022/unanswered-questions-on-stackoverflow http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/is-there-a-page-that-display-questions-with-0-answers ... Searching is good

Comment: I did search and didn't find those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of **unanswered**, at least on StackOverflow, is:

> A question in which no answers have been up voted.

Or, taken directly from the sidebar:

> 4,529 questions with **no upvoted answers**.

This means that there might be 50 or so answers to a question, but if none of them were up voted, it is technically an unanswered question.

Comment: Also see the SO blog post [OK, Now Define "Answered"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/)

Comment: Ah, I see that now.  So confusing at first because it says "4 answers" or "2 answers", etc. right beside each question.  A tool-tip for the link would help a ton.

Comment: Jeff should definitely stop writing things in that right column. Useful informations, formatting advices... nobody sees them anyway.

Comment: Ya, I noticed it after the fact.  I guess it's not obvious that it's related to the section I'm viewing.  I'm sure it's useful for other things though.

A tool tip for the section buttons would work very well (I notice lots of nice tool tips elsewhere on the site).